# How to send an itemised PayPal invoice to user and merchant?

Tags: javascript, html, paypal, shopping-cart

I am developing a website that contains a store. A user can pay with PayPal on this store and this work perfectly! The shopping cart is programmed using JavaScript and this has caused a few issues.

I originally wanted to have a JS function that sent the user an email with their cart but I could find any code for that. I know that you can get an itemised receipt using PayPal but my system won't give me those details. I've read through the developer part of the PayPal website but I can't seem to figure it out!

My PayPal script is below:

```js
<script>
        paypal.Buttons({
            createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                // This function sets up the details of the transaction, including the amount and line item details.
                return actions.order.create({
                    purchase_units: [{
                        amount: {
                            value: countCartTotal()
                        }
                    }]
                });
            },
            onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                // This function captures the funds from the transaction.
                return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                    // This function shows a transaction success message to your buyer.
                    window.location.href = "orderConfirmed.php"
                    clearCart()
                });
            }
        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
        //This function displays Smart Payment Buttons on your web page.
    </script>
```

The shopping cart is coded in cart.js and I know I can use a function from this file in the PayPal script as the function 'countCartTotal()' is what tell PayPal the amount to charge the customers. In my cart. js, this is how I add items to the cart:

```js
function insertItemToDOM(product) {
    cartDOM.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
    <div class="cart__item">
      <img class="cart__item__image" src="${product.image}" alt="${product.name}">
      <h3 class="cart__item__name">${product.name}</h3>
      <h3 class="cart__item__price">${product.price}</h3>
      <button class="btn btn--primary btn--small${(product.quantity === 1 ? ' btn--danger' : '')}" data-action="DECREASE_ITEM">&minus;</button>
      <h3 class="cart__item__quantity">${product.quantity}</h3>
      <button class="btn btn--primary btn--small" data-action="INCREASE_ITEM">&plus;</button>
      <button class="btn btn--danger btn--small" data-action="REMOVE_ITEM">&times;</button>
    </div>
  `);

    addCartFooter();
}
```

I need to have the Paypal contain the '${product.name}' and the '${product.quantity}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Items go in the `purchase_units` array, documented [at v2/orders](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-purchase_unit_request). It can be hard to understand all the required breakdown parameters, which *must* add up or the checkout will error and not open -- so here is an example with two items:

```
"purchase_units": [{
      "description": "Stuff",
      "amount": {
        "value": "20.00",
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "breakdown": {
          "item_total": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "20.00"
          },
        }
      },
      "items": [
        {
          "unit_amount": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "10.00"
          },
          "quantity": "1",
          "name": "Item 1",
        },
        {
          "unit_amount": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "10.00"
          },
          "quantity": "1",
          "name": "Item 2",
        },
      ],
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Thank you! What if the user adds more than 2 items tho? How would that work?

Comment: You would have a longer array with more items, or the quantity of the items already in the array would be higher, and all the totals would be updated to match

Comment: Ohh okay, so I just add in all the items I have in the store?

Comment: No, you need to set purchase_units to the items being purchased by that particular customer, during that particular payment attempt

Comment: Okay Thanks, would you be able to explain more on how to do that or know where I should look, I don't have a lot of experience in javascript!

Comment: I can't offer much particular advice; but yes, it's a straightforward javascript/web design task so you can probably take it as an opportunity to practice and learn as if it were a homework problem